# My base64 concatenated string has = characters. How to get rid of them

Tags: javascript, string, base64, concatenation

How should I concatenate base64 strings in order to get rid of the "=" characters ?

I sent a byte stream[] of data from the servlet as a http response, and at the client side I want to open the pdf viewer. But, I can't view it because of these extra characters.

I tried to concatenate with +=, with join, with concat, but I still have the = character at the end of each substring.

Maybe if there's a way to concat the strings without the last character.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: You cannot concat base64 if they end with `=` strings; you must unencode and reencode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard base-64 encoding encodes three bytes (3 * 8 bits) into 4 characters (4 * 6 bits). If the number of bytes in the original data is not divisible by 3, 2 `=` characters are added if the remainder was 1, and 1 `=` is added if the remainder was 2.

Now, unfortunately you cannot concatenate 2 base-64 encoded strings if the first ends with padding characters `=` - you must decode both, concatenate the binary string*, and then re-encode, otherwise the latter part will be out of sync and all bytes of the second part will be decoded incorrectly.

[*] it is not strictly necessary to re-encode the first part in its entirety but optimizing for that is not necessarily worthwhile.

Comment: So I have to find a way to concatenate on bits in javascript. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I do understand your question, but for me it sounds like you want to concatenate multiple Base64-encoded strings and then decode them. This won't work regardless of the `=`-characters.

For example take a look at the following Base64-encodings:

```
X20    -> IA==
X20 20 -> ICA=
```

But concatenating `IAIA` and decoding it will result in `X 20 02 00`.

The reason why it can't work is that each character in Base64-coded form may represent parts from more than one unencoded byte and each unencoded byte might be represented in more than one Base64-character.

So as Antti Haapala correctly stated: you have to decode first and then conactenate the output instead of vice versa.

Comment: If there are no `=` *and* it was encoded with a scheme that uses `==` for padding, then it *would* be possible to concatenate.