# How can you concatenate data urls?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm streaming data from a file upload a la [javascript FileReader - parsing long file in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438187/javascript-filereader-parsing-long-file-in-chunks) in browser javascript.

Basically its reading a file in chunks by doing:

```
var r = new FileReader()
var blob = file.slice(curPosition, curPosition+chunkSize); 
r.onload = function(e) {
  emit('data', e.target.result)
}
r.readAsDataURL(blob)
```

It does this as many times as necessary to read the whole file.

But when I do this, I get the data-url preamble each time, then a bunch of base64 data. Even when I remove the preamble, simple string concatenation doesn't work (the file ends up corrupted).

How can you concatenate two data urls? Or really, I think this question boils down to: how do you concatenate two base64 strings?

Alternatively, how do you build a data url in pure javascript?

Comment: Can you please give us more details ?

Comment: @A.J. Accidentally submitted it guys, keep yer dern pernts ern.

Comment: _"I'm streaming data from a file upload"_ What do you mean by "streaming data"? To which element? Why would there be more than single `data URI`? Are you trying to render multiple files sequentially at an `HTMLMediaElement`? _"I get its preamble"_ What is "preamble"?

Comment: @guest271314 Please read the top answer from the link I included in my question. The answer slices up a single file into bite sized chunks so your browser doesn't lock up on larger files. This is uploading it directly into your browser page's memory, not a server.

Comment: Yes, read linked Question. Not certain how linked Question is related to concatenating `data URL`s? What do you mean by "streaming data"? Can you include `html`, `javascript` that you have tried at Question?, create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 I added some more explanation. By streaming data, I mean processing a file in chunks.

Comment: `javascript` at Question does not pass `file` to `r.readAsDataURL()`? What is `file`? `r.readAsDataURL()` would return `data URL` of that portion of `file`, resulting in `chunkSize` `data URL`'s

Comment: You could probably use `.readAsArrayBuffer()` to create "slices" or "chunks" of files which combined are single file. What are you trying to stream? Not certain it is possible to "stream" a `data URL`. Is `file` a text, audio or video file?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, typo, its supposed to pass `blob` to `readAsDataURL`. `file` is a `File` object. Shouldn't matter what's in the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "stream"? Stream text, audio, video, bytes? Does a `DOM` element render the stream, or output from `FileReader`? What is purpose of using `.readAsDataURL()` instead of `.readAsArrayBuffer()`?

Comment: @guest271314 I already answered that.. Processing the file in chunks. Its an arbitrary file. You're looking for meaning where there is none. I'm *testing* by generating a data URL for an image and displaying that image in the dom, but that's not the only usecase.

Comment: You can use `.readAsArrayBuffer()`, `load`, `loadend` , `progress` events of `FileReader()` to read, process, stream each byte of `ArrayBuffer` of `File` object returned by `.readAsArrayBuffer()` to achieve expected result

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concatenate two base64-encoded strings, try this:

```
var data1 = ..., data2 = ...; // base64 encoded
var bothData = atob(data1) + atob(data2); // binary string
var bothData64 = btoa(bothData); // base64 encoded
```

`atob` converts base64 into plain old (binary) strings, which can be concatenated as usual. If you want to convert it back into base64, use `btoa`. See the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding).

If you want to stream a file into a `data:` URL, you could also use `.readAsArrayBuffer()`, concatenate the results (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786128/appending-arraybuffers)), and convert the `ArrayBuffer` to base64 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267899/arraybuffer-to-base64-encoded-string)).

Comment: `Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded` What would be result of `bothData` ?

Comment: `data1` and `data2` must be just the base64 part of the `data:` URL, e.g., without the `data:foo/bar;base64,`

Comment: This sounds awfully inefficient. Remember I'm processing large files (think gigabytes).

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to decode the base64 to concatenate it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29080108/1848578). You can save the re-encoding for the very end, or skip it if you just need the binary data.

Comment: Also the bottleneck will almost certainly be the network connection, and not some meager client processing like this.

Comment: I'm not sending the data over a network connection, just directly onto the browser page. Bottleneck or not, it would be simpler and more efficient to create a full ArrayBuffer and generate a data URL from it all at once than to do this. I'm 99% sure you can concatenate base64 strings as long as you handle the padding characters which only appear at the end. In my case, this will be at most 3 characters out of 64000. The note about the padding characters is helpful tho, thanks!

Comment: You can't just play with the padding characters; one byte can be encoded in multiple base64 chars. See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prnav1Lq/) and [this page](https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/base64_explained) on how base64 works. I've also edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

in nodejs

```
    function joinBase64Strings(base64Str1, base64Str2) {
      const bothData = Buffer.from(base64Str1, 'base64').toString('binary') 
            + Buffer.from(base64Str2, 'base64').toString('binary');
      const joinedBase64Result = Buffer.from(bothData.toString(), 'binary').toString('base64');
      console.log('joinedBase64Result', joinedBase64Result);
      return joinedBase64Result;
    }
```

Comment: I just made this a little more clear, but my question is specifically about browser-side javascript

Comment: @BT It bad practice do convertation in browser, do it on backend

Comment: Convertation? What do you mean by that? I'm streaming data from the frontend to the backend, so its literally impossible to "do it on [the] backend".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.readAsArrayBuffer()`, `progress`, `load`, `loadend`  events of `FileReader` to create a new `Blob` or `File` object, or to stream each byte of data returned as `.result` by `.readAsArrayBuffer(/* Blob or File object */)`